# C++ Unexpected NaN

Tags: c++

I'm coding a project work right now, and my latest problem is that the output gives NaN after a while (then persistently, of course), but with my limited knowledge I can't figure out why. I read a bit about where NaN usually comes from ( 0/0, inf*0, etc.), but that doesn't seem to be the case here. While the whole code is too long and complex to post here, I already determined the part of code it seems to come from:

```
long double force_dipol(particle &part1, particle &part2, long double distance) {
    if ((abstand(part1.dummyd)!=0) && (abstand(part2.dummyd)!=0) { //Division checks
        long double ret;
        ret = 3.*( part1.dummyd[0]*part2.dummyd[0] + part1.dummyd[1]*part2.dummyd[1] + part1.dummyd[2]*part2.dummyd[2] ) / mypow(distance, 3);
        ret -= 9.*abstand(part1.dummyd)*abstand(part2.dummyd) / mypow(distance, 3) * (part1.dummyd[2]/abstand(part1.dummyd) * part2.dummyd[2]/abstand(part2.dummyd));
        return ret;
    }
}
```

For any who care, its the force term of a dipole-dipole interaction (yay, physics!).

- particle is my structure that just keeps the variables together.
- dummyd is a [3]-Array that is the dipole moment, its components range from roughly -5 to 5, at max
- abstand() is the vector norm, mathematically speaking, and abstand(dummyd) is between 0.6 and 2.5
- distance ranges from 2.4 to 5.6
- mypow() is just custom pow() for performance
- the 3. and 9. are numbers XP
- all variables used are long double

Additionally, if I comment out the first term of the function (the line below `long double ret`) it seems to stop NaN'ing, while the second term (the line after that, the longer one) seems to work.

The function above is part of a whole algorithm that gets iterated a few million times in total; somewhere along the line, the output of the position and momentum arrays (which use this function) starts to get only NaN and keeps it from there. To actually filter the output is quite a bit of work, but so far it seems it gets there from normal values (that is, in the expected range, nowhere near big numbers).

Now, I want to understand why I get NaN in this case, and how to fix it. Anyone who can explain to me gets +10 awesomeness.

Answer (score 5):

You don't `return` anything when the `if` condition fails. This will lead to undefined behavior if you use the "returned" value.

Comment: Good answer. If the OP still has trouble, putting an `if` statement in to check the result should enable you to print the troublesome inputs and, if necessary, place a breakpoint to invoke the debugger..

Comment: +1. I was busy checking the maths, I didn't think to check the code!

Comment: @user2995421 Out of curiosity: Didn't your compiler warn you about "control reaches end of non-void function", or did you ignore the warnings?

Answer (score 2):

No return value is one possibility, but also what does `mypow()` do when `distance` is 0?

0 to the 3 = 0, so you have a divide by zero there too (unless `mypow()` handles that).

Try:

```
long double force_dipol(particle &part1, particle &part2, long double distance)
{
  long double ret = 0;
  if ((abstand(part1.dummyd)!=0) && (abstand(part2.dummyd)!=0) && (distance!=0)) //Division checks
  {
    ret = 3.*( part1.dummyd[0]*part2.dummyd[0] + part1.dummyd[1]*part2.dummyd[1] + part1.dummyd[2]*part2.dummyd[2] ) / mypow(distance, 3);
    ret -= 9.*abstand(part1.dummyd)*abstand(part2.dummyd) / mypow(distance, 3) * (part1.dummyd[2]/abstand(part1.dummyd) * part2.dummyd[2]/abstand(part2.dummyd));
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: No, mypow() doesn't handle anything, but distance can't be 0 either. In fact I'm making a habit of checking everything I divide by, but here its really not necessary. Just for good measure I copied cour code and tried, but the problem stayed.

Comment: @user2995421: "I'm making a habit of checking everything I divide by, but here its really not necessary" - that is never true :O, especially in an isolated function where the /zero hasn't been checked. If the implementation of `mypow` changes, it will leave potential crashes in other parts of your code. Best practice is to use defensive programming.